# Fixing Python requests.exception.InvalidURL : Invalid percent-escape sequence 'u2' error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping, urllib

My python app accepts url's processed using Javascript `escape` function which are `unescaped` using `urllib.unquote` in my python code, this works fine for most url's but fails if the file-name (which is also part of the url) contains a `&` in it with following error.

`requests.exception.InvalidURL : Invalid percent-escape sequence 'u2'`

**Edit: Example code with error**

```
import urllib,requests
url = "https%3A//r20---sn-cvh7zn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback%3Fipbits%3D0%26ms%3Dau%26fexp%3D931328%2C931946%2C934804%2C914004%2C931818%2C937417%2C913434%2C923328%2C936916%2C934022%2C936923%26sparams%3Dclen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire%26source%3Dyoutube%26mv%3Dm%26dur%3D278.593%26id%3Do-AOxIEhMchATdRjU99Gveow8reeBWtxFaqwpWifXC9KwS%26expire%3D1397662367%26clen%3D4425254%26sver%3D3%26signature%3D9A0CFEC5F59C2C7FC35A8CF87491F4E7F9683C59.C46B3A3602A20611C73CC4228FCB8B287034F52D%26mt%3D1397639060%26upn%3DBknKrHPqCCw%26gir%3Dyes%26itag%3D140%26key%3Dyt5%26ip%3D117.200.252.163%26lmt%3D1386126879207085%26requiressl%3Dyes%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26title%3DHum%20Tuhmaray%20hain%20%u2022%20SRK%20_%20Madhuri%20Dixit%20%u2022%20HD%201080p%20%u2022%20Hindi%20%u2022%20Bollywood%20Songs"
url = urllib.unquote_plus(url).decode('utf-8')
resp = requests.head(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
print resp
```

The string `Hum Tuhmaray hain • SRK & Madhuri Dixit •` causes issues, the problem seems to be the unicode bullet character `%u2022` in the url.

Comment: Can you show your code + one working example and one non-working example?

Comment: Check the problematic url above, this fails with error Invalid percent-escape sequence 'u2' when using this `resp = requests.head(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)`

Comment: This URL doesn't work in a browser either. Why don't you use the original URL, and let the `urllib` worry about the special-character encoding?

Comment: This is what I get from my javascript code, this needs to be unescaped.

Comment: The string Hum Tuhmaray hain • SRK & Madhuri Dixit • causes issues, the problem seems to be the unicode bullet character %u2022 in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Using `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript code instead of `escape()` fixed the issue.

Thanks